# Import Dttools in Python

Tags: python

Is there any prepared function in python to include the Dttools (for example Butterworth filter) to a given signal? I want to import the dttolls in scipy for my program, how do I do that?

Comment: try: `import Dttools`

Answer (score 1):

Dttools inst included in the standard libray, but you can download it [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~thain/research/dttools/), install it, and the use

```
import Dttools
```

or

```
 from Dttools import (name of methods you want)
```

to import it to your program. Make sure you have Dttools on your python path or else python wont know where it is. Also, here is a little more about importing from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/import.html).

You'll then be able to access Dttools with syntax like `Dttools.tool()` ect.